Carboxylic acid with Phosphoric acid

When this reactant is reacted with Phosphoric acid we obtain

The mechanism in the book given was carboxylic acid is a weak acid and phosphoric acid is a strong acid.  And not more than that.
I am seeking a detailed explanation of the reaction mechanism between a weak acid and a strong acid here. Specifically, I am interested in understanding the role each acid plays in the process and the key steps involved. Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

The reagent used is usually polyphosphoric acid, a mixture of phosphoric acid and phopshorus pentoxide which is a dehydrating agent. This dehydrates the carboxylic acid, giving R-CO+ which does an electrophilic attack on the aromatic ring.

So Phosphoric acid is basically dehydrating the carboxylic acid.  Then why in the class they have reasoned with acidic strength of the acids.  Do acidic strength of the acid play any role here.

Dehydration is catalyzed by strong acids, able to protonize OH group in carboxyl, what allows water elimination and formation R-C(+)O cation

Phosphoric acid is a stronger acid than carboxylic acid and hence it catalyzes the dehydration of carboxylic acid by removing the OH group generating C(+) carbocation.  Since it is an electrophile it undergoes electrophilic attack on aromatic benzene ring.
